# get and convert facebook feeds in local language

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website built in local language (like Urdu for Pakistan, Chinese for china etc), in that site I am getting Facebook page feeds using graph API and showing on a page, now my problem is those feeds are being shown in English language but I want to show them in local language

like if some one updated his status as "Good Morning" I am getting that feed in Pakistan then I have to show it like "صبح بخیر".

can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `locale` parameter, but that doesn't cause content to be auto-translated.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#readmodifiers